# web scraping with lxml to discord, how do i pull text and photo links?

Tags: python, lxml, discord

Im using lxml to pull products from a bunch of retailers, and sending the info to a discord server.
I have majority of it done, beside scraping a link (for a picture etc: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b05aca03-968b-4e43-8b48-781aa52ef3e0_1.7fa663da8e1c382271e6649007e9a60b.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF)

and text, to get the items name and price.

here is a picture of what the embed discord webhook would look like

Product im trying to scrape: https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP/295232252

example of the element im trying to pull the image from: (src=)

`<img class="hover-zoom-hero-image" src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b05aca03-968b-4e43-8b48-781aa52ef3e0_1.7fa663da8e1c382271e6649007e9a60b.png?odnHeight=450&amp;odnWidth=450&amp;odnBg=FFFFFF" alt="Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin">`

example of the element im trying to pull text from:(content=)

`<h1 class="prod-ProductTitle no-margin font-normal heading-a" itemprop="name" content="Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin"><div>Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin</div></h1>`

My code:

```
def send_embed(link):
embed = Embed(
description=link,
color=color_embed,
timestamp='now' # sets the timestamp to current time
)
image1 = 'https://www.blakleysflooring.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Placeholder.png'
image2 = pic

embed.set_author(name=itemName + "|" + price, url=link)
embed.add_field(name='Retailer', value=site)
embed.add_field(name='Stock', value=instock)
embed.set_footer(text='@QuantumPings')

embed.set_thumbnail(image2)
hook.send(embed=embed)


def getDatetime():
return '[{}]'.format(str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-3])


def monitor(link):
global embed
global itemName
global pic
global site
global instock
global price
global color_embed
try:
with session as s:
r = s.get(link, timeout=10)
r.raise_for_status()

tree = etree.HTML(r.content)
if 'walmart' in link:
oos = False if tree.xpath('//span[@class="button-wrapper"]') else True
site = 'Walmart'
instock = False if tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span') else False
pic = ()
itemName = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProductTitle"]/h2/div/text()')
price = '$0.00'
color_embed = 0x00f714 if instock is True else 0xff0008
 True else 0xff0008
```

Comment: Would you be ok using `BeautifulSoup` instead? I haven't worked with `lxml` but parsing text with `BeautifulSoup` is ez-pz

Comment: @Reedinationer id prefer not to, but if it comes down to it i guess i could.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of how to use `lxml` to gather text / links. You can pretty much do anything with `lxml` so for sure experiment. And on a side note I think `lxml` is faster than `BeautifulSoup` but it is not as elegant. I would also read over https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

```
from lxml import html

response = """
<h1 class="prod-ProductTitle no-margin font-normal heading-a" itemprop="name" content="Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin"><div>Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin</div></h1>
<img class="hover-zoom-hero-image" src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b05aca03-968b-4e43-8b48-781aa52ef3e0_1.7fa663da8e1c382271e6649007e9a60b.png?odnHeight=450&amp;odnWidth=450&amp;odnBg=FFFFFF" alt="Funko POP! Marvel: Avengers Endgame -&nbsp;Ronin">
"""

tree = html.fromstring(response)

title = [e for e in tree.cssselect('h1') if e.get('itemprop') is not None and e.get('itemprop') == 'name']
title = title[0]
title = title.text_content()
print (title)

img = tree.cssselect('img.hover-zoom-hero-image')
img = img[0]
img = img.get('src')
print (img)
```

Comment: the problem is i need it to work with alot of links, and i would not like to put the elements individually for each product. itemName= doesnt work for me at the moment i get an error "can only concatenate list (not "str) to list" in my setup

Comment: I am using `itemprop` not `itemname`? And if your requesting many urls at once, use something like `aiohttp` but that is not going to change how you gather the `title` / `link`.